# JavaScript to change select option when changing image

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have some simple JavaScript to change an image by clicking on buttons.  I'd like to correspond that with the appropriate option in a particular select statement.  The button changer works as we like, I'd just like to add something to it to also change the select option every time the button is changed.

```
<img src="https://robinsonswoodcrafts.com/images/StainColors/11_maple_EnglishChestnut.jpg" id="stainImage" alt="">
    <p>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_Goldenoak.jpg'">Golden Oak</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_Natural.jpg'">Natural</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_Earlyamerican.jpg'">Early American</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_RedMahogany.jpg'">Red Mahogany</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_Puritanpine.jpg'">Puritan</button>
    </p>
```

These particular stain colors correspond with a form that the user will select as part of an order form using a shopping cart.  The select statement is like this:

```
           <div class="form__item">
                <label for="staincolor" class="form__label">Stain Color</label>
                    <select name="staincolor" id="stainColor">
                        <option value="">[ No Stain ]</option>
                        <option id="sc-goldenoak" value="Golden Oak {p+1.50}">
                            Golden Oak
                        </option>
                        <option id="sc-natural" value="Natural {p+1.50}">
                            Natural
                        </option>
                        <option id="sc-earlyamerican" value="Early American {p+1.50}">
                            Early American
                        </option>
                        <option id="sc-redmahogany" value="Red Mahogany {p+1.50}">
                            Red Mahogany
                        </option>
                        <option id="sc-puritanpine" value="Puritan Pine {p+1.50}">
                            Puritan Pine
                        </option>
                </select>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this. You can store your variants with corresponding filenames (or vice versa) and then in your buttons use simple function to do both operations - change image and select option in your select input.

```js
const fileNames = {
  'Golden Oak {p+1.50}': '1_pine_Goldenoak.jpg',
  'Natural {p+1.50}': '1_pine_Natural.jpg'
}

function selectColor(option) {
  document.getElementById('stainImage').src = 'https://robinsonswoodcrafts.com/images/StainColors/' + fileNames[option];
  document.getElementById('stainColor').value = option
}
```

```html
<img src="https://robinsonswoodcrafts.com/images/StainColors/11_maple_EnglishChestnut.jpg" id="stainImage" alt="">
<p>
  <button onclick="selectColor('Golden Oak {p+1.50}')">Golden Oak</button>
  <button onclick="selectColor('Natural {p+1.50}')">Natural</button>
</p>

<div class="form__item">
  <label for="staincolor" class="form__label">Stain Color</label>
  <select name="staincolor" id="stainColor">
    <option value="">[ No Stain ]</option>
    <option id="sc-goldenoak" value="Golden Oak {p+1.50}">
      Golden Oak
    </option>
    <option id="sc-natural" value="Natural {p+1.50}">
      Natural
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this option a lot, pretty simple to replicate and does what I need.  The only thing I'm running into is that even though it changes the select option it doesn't update the running price total, but that has more to do with the shopping cart than the JS you wrote.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

my way, with event delegation...

```js
const imgPath    = 'https://robinsonswoodcrafts.com/images/StainColors/'
  ,   r_ImgBtSel =
    [ { lib: 'Golden Oak',     val: 'Golden Oak {p+1.50}',     img: '1_pine_Goldenoak.jpg'     }
    , { lib: 'Natural',        val: 'Natural {p+1.50}',        img: '1_pine_Natural.jpg'       }
    , { lib: 'Early American', val: 'Early American {p+1.50}', img: '1_pine_Earlyamerican.jpg' }
    , { lib: 'Red Mahogany',   val: 'Red Mahogany {p+1.50}',   img: '1_pine_RedMahogany.jpg'   }
    , { lib: 'Puritan',        val: 'Puritan Pine {p+1.50}',   img: '1_pine_Puritanpine.jpg'   }
    ]
const stainImage = document.getElementById('stainImage')
  ,   grpBtns    = document.getElementById('group-buttons-xyz')
  ,   stainColor = document.querySelector('select#stainColor')
  ;
r_ImgBtSel.forEach(el=>  // create buttons and options from r_ImgBtSel values
  {
  let bt = document.createElement('button')
  bt.textContent = el.lib
  grpBtns.appendChild(bt)
  stainColor.add( new Option(el.lib, el.val))
  })
grpBtns.onclick = ev =>  // event lisener delegation for buttons
  {
  if (!ev.target.matches('button')) return  // reject other clicks on p area
  let info = r_ImgBtSel.find(x=>x.lib===ev.target.textContent ) 
  stainImage.setAttribute('src', imgPath + info.img )  // set img
  stainColor.value = info.val                          // set option
  }
stainColor.onchange =e=>
  {
  let info = r_ImgBtSel.find(x=>x.val===stainColor.value )
  stainImage.setAttribute('src', imgPath + info.img )  // set img
  }
```

```html
<img id="stainImage" src="https://robinsonswoodcrafts.com/images/StainColors/11_maple_EnglishChestnut.jpg" alt="">

<p id="group-buttons-xyz"></p>

<div class="form__item">
  <label for="staincolor" class="form__label">Stain Color</label>
    <select name="staincolor" id="stainColor">
      <option value="" selected disabled >[ No Stain ]</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!! it works :)

```js
let button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
let stainColor = document.getElementById('stainColor');

Array.from(button).forEach(ele => {
      ele.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            
            stainColor.value = e.target.innerHTML + ' {p+1.50}'
           
            
       })
       
});
```

```html
<img src="https://robinsonswoodcrafts.com/images/StainColors/11_maple_EnglishChestnut.jpg" id="stainImage" alt="">
    <p>
        <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_Goldenoak.jpg'">Golden Oak</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_Natural.jpg'">Natural</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_Earlyamerican.jpg'">Early American</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_RedMahogany.jpg'">Red Mahogany</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('stainImage').src='images/StainColors/1_pine_Puritanpine.jpg'">Puritan</button>
    </p>

<div class="form__item">
                <label for="staincolor" class="form__label">Stain Color</label>
                    <select name="staincolor" id="stainColor">
                        <option value="">[ No Stain ]</option>
                        <option id="sc-goldenoak" value="Golden Oak {p+1.50}">
                            Golden Oak
                        </option>
                        <option id="sc-natural" value="Natural {p+1.50}">
                            Natural
                        </option>
                        <option id="sc-earlyamerican" value="Early American {p+1.50}">
                            Early American
                        </option>
                        <option id="sc-redmahogany" value="Red Mahogany {p+1.50}">
                            Red Mahogany
                        </option>
                        <option id="sc-puritanpine" value="Puritan {p+1.50}">
                            Puritan Pine
                        </option>
                </select>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, I hope it is useful to you:

```js
    const fileList={
                        "Golden Oak":{
                            "imgSrc":"images/StainColors/1_pine_Goldenoak.jpg",
                            "optionId":"sc-goldenoak"
                        },
                        "Natural":{
                            "imgSrc":"images/StainColors/1_pine_Natural.jpg",
                            "optionId":"sc-natural"
                        },
                        "Early American":{
                            "imgSrc":"images/StainColors/1_pine_Earlyamerican.jpg",
                            "optionId":"sc-earlyamerican"
                        },
                        "Red Mahogany":{
                            "imgSrc":"images/StainColors/1_pine_RedMahogany.jpg",
                            "optionId":"sc-redmahogany"
                        },
                        "Puritan":{
                            "imgSrc":"images/StainColors/1_pine_Puritanpine.jpg",
                            "optionId":"sc-puritanpine"
            }
                    };
          
function changeSomething(key){
    var img=document.getElementById("stainImage");
  img.src=fileList[key].imgSrc;
  document.getElementById(fileList[key].optionId).selected=true;    
  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://robinsonswoodcrafts.com/images/StainColors/11_maple_EnglishChestnut.jpg" id="stainImage" alt="">
<p>
  <button onclick="changeSomething(this.textContent)">Golden Oak</button>
  <button onclick="changeSomething(this.textContent)">Natural</button>
  <button onclick="changeSomething(this.textContent)">Early American</button>
  <button onclick="changeSomething(this.textContent)">Red Mahogany</button>
  <button onclick="changeSomething(this.textContent)">Puritan</button>
</p>

<div class="form__item">
  <label for="staincolor" class="form__label">Stain Color</label>
  <select name="staincolor" id="stainColor">
    <option value="">[ No Stain ]</option>
    <option id="sc-goldenoak" value="Golden Oak {p+1.50}">
      Golden Oak
    </option>
    <option id="sc-natural" value="Natural {p+1.50}">
      Natural
    </option>
    <option id="sc-earlyamerican" value="Early American {p+1.50}">
      Early American
    </option>
    <option id="sc-redmahogany" value="Red Mahogany {p+1.50}">
      Red Mahogany
    </option>
    <option id="sc-puritanpine" value="Puritan Pine {p+1.50}">
      Puritan Pine
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```